# problems with Ext namespace from Sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

## 1 I created "npm create-react-app" project and on it, I applied this Sencha's instructions:

http://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.5.0/guides/using_create_react_app.html

In, src/index.js replace:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

with:

```
import { launch } from '@extjs/reactor';
```

and replace

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

with:

```
launch(<App />);
```

when I do this step of replacing those 2 lines with the new 2 lines.
I get error:

```
./node_modules/@extjs/reactor/dist/ExtJSComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/lib/DOMLazyTree' in 'C:\Users\Dev36\Desktop\MILOS\client\node_modules\@extjs\reactor\dist'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that; althougth they said Ext React 6.5.3 suppport react 16 (https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-extreact-6-5-3-ga-and-react-16-ea/), is not true. Try downgrading react and react-dom to 15.5.4